# Intercepting NHibernate Lazy-Load behaviour to return null if not connected to a session?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, soa

This seems like it should be an obvious thing but I've been searching for the answer for hours now with no success.

I'm using NHibernate to persist a domain model, with a service layer that serves an ASP.NET MVC front end (the 'service layer' is currently just a standard class library but may be converted to WCF in the future). The web app asks for the data it wants and specifies the collections on the domain object that it needs, the service layer takes the request, loads the object and required collections (using lazy loading) and passes the object back where it is transformed using AutoMapper to a viewmodel friendly representation.

What I want to be able to do is load the required collections, detach the object from the session and pass it to the front end. However, when AutoMapper tries to map the object this causes a an exception because it's trying to access collections that haven't been initialized and the session is no longer available. I can leave the object connected but in this case the AutoMapper transformation ends up causing all the properties on the object to be lazy-loaded anyway and this won't be an option is we go down the WCF route.

What I want to do is alter this behaviour so that instead of throwing an exception, the collection returns null (or better yet empty) when it is not connected to a session. This was the default behaviour in Entity Framework V1 (which admittedly didn't do auto lazy loading), which I worked with previously but I can't find a way to do it in NH.

Any ideas? Am I on the wrong track here?

EDIT- To be a bit clearer on what I'm trying to achieve, when accessing a collection property I want this behaviour:

Connected to session: lazy-load collection as normal.
No session: property is null (rather than throw exception)

UPDATE - Following [this post](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2007/12/07/custom-collections-with-nhibernate-part-iii-refactored.aspx) by Billy McCafferty, I've managed to implement a solution using IUserCollectionType that seems to work so far. Rather than use the provided PersistentGenericBag as he does though, I had to create new types that changed the behaviour when not connected to the session. It's not perfect and requires some very ugly mappings but at least I don't need to touch my domain objects or client mappings to get it working.

Comment: Do you mean that collections are lazy loaded, or (also) properties of classes that are marked as lazy in your nhibernate mapping? Maybe you can post sample code of a domain class and a corresponding view model class.

Comment: Yes, lazy loaded collections. My domain classes are a fairly uncomplicated mix of standard properties and collections. These get mapped to DTO type classes in the web app. A viewmodel will likely consist of several of these classes.

Comment: Ah ok, I see what you are getting at. Yes you are correct that my DTOs are not very specific and I could avoid the problem by creating a DTO for every usage scenario, but that would result in a lot of similar classes and duplication, which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: DTOs are meant to be specifically created for each individual data transfer process. There may even be different DTOs for in and out messages of one call! Of course you should reuse them where possible (Dino Esposito even "allows" using domain objects if they suffice), but never hesitate to make a few more. That's what Automapper was made for.

Comment: While I don't disagree with what you say, doing this would complicate the front-end code considerably and I'm somewhat loathe to rearchitect an unrelated part of the app to make up for shortfalls in the persistence framework. I appreciate your input though, I hadn't really considered it from that angle and I'll certainly have a think about the way I've implemented my domain model -> view model mappings. For the time being though I may have found a way to achieve what I'm attempting using NHibernate custom collection types, I'll update my question if I get anywhere with it.

Comment: What is the behavior of NHibernate's stateless session in this situation?

Comment: Pete, can you provide more details on how you got around this problem? I too would like to touch lazy collections outside the session and not blow up into an exception. I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Unfortunately the solution I mentioned in my update didn't work out as well as I'd hoped and broke lots of things so I abandoned that approach in the end.

Comment: In the end I wrote a sort of deep clone which returns a clean copy of a domain object with only the collections that have been initialised already populated. I pass in the properties I want populating to my repository, it fetches the object and lazy-loads those properties then passes back a clean copy to the calling method. My implementation was a bit clumsy though.

Comment: Can't you configure mapping rules for the AutoMapper to just avoid mapping those lazy-loaded collections? I know that AutoMapper can be told how to map each field, although I am not sure if it can be told to completely ignore something to avoid triggering lazy-load.

Comment: AutoMapper has an Ignore function that is commonly set during CreateMap.  You could use it to ignore lazy-loaded fields.  Of course this doesn't help you auto-detect & ignore when the session is not active and doesn't detect lazy loaded fields that have been loaded as a result of accessing the field... but it's a step in the right direction if you end up hand-rolling your solution.

Answer (score 2):

The most appropriate solution in this case is probably to check in AutoMapper for lazy-loadable fields if they were indeed loaded with NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(). Not sure how/if possible to make Automapper use this check for all implicit property mappings though.

Old question but this is what we did to solve the same issue, hopefully it helps to set you on correct path if somebody stumbles upon this problem.